# Text segmentation: Algorithm to match input with the longest words from the dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, text-segmentation

I need to split a string into words such that each word comes from a dictionary. Also make sure that longest possible word from the left is chosen. Hence

```
thisisinsane => this is insane (correct as longest possible word from left)
thisisinsane => this is in sane(wrong) 
Assuming 'this', 'is', 'in', 'insane' are all words in the dictionary.
```

I managed to solved this problem by traversing from the end of the string to the beginning matching longest word possible. But problem started cropping us for problems like these..

```
shareasale => share as ale(wrong as 'ale' not in the dictionary)
shareasale => share a sale(correct)
Assuming 'share', 'a', 'sale' are all words in the dictionary unlike 'ale'.
```

I tried to solve this problem by removing the valid segments found before encountering the error i.e.

```
shareasale => 'share' and 'as' (error = 'ale')
```

and removing them once from the dictionary and then solve the problem. So

```
shareasale => no valid segments when share is removed
shareasale => share a sale (when 'as' is removed from the dictionary.
```

Thus I managed to solve this problem too. But then I am unable to solve this

```
asignas => 'as' ( error = 'ignas')
```

My solution will then remove 'as' from the dictionary and try to solve it

```
asignas => 'a' 'sign' (error = 'as')
```

Because in the new recursive call 'as' has been removed from the dictionary. The function I wrote is [in this link](http://pastebin.com/VMKC007Q). I hope someone can go through it and help me find a better algorithm to solve this else suggest modification to my existing algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially your problem is a tree problem, where at every level all the words that form a prefix of the tree form branches. The branch that leaves no part of the string is a correct solution.

```
                      thisisinsane
                          |
                          |
                     (this)isinsane
                     /            \
                    /              \
          (this,i)sinsane         (this,is)insane
              /                     /           \
             /                     /             \
  (this,i,sin)ane          (this,is,in)sane    (this,is,insane)
                                /
                               /
                       (this,is,in,sane)
```

So in this example there are two solutions, but we want to select the solution using the longest words, that is we want to explore the tree from the right using a depth-first-search strategy.

So our algorithm should:

1. Sort the dictionary by descending length.
2. Find all prefixes of the current string. If there are none, return `False`.
3. Set `prefix` to the longest unexplored prefix.
4. Remove it from the string. If the string is empty, we found a solution, return a list of all prefixes.
5. Recurse to 2.
6. This branch has failed, return `False`.

---

A sample implementation of this solution:

```
def segment(string,wset):
    """Segments a string into words prefering longer words givens
    a dictionary wset."""
    # Sort wset in decreasing string order
    wset.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    result = tokenize(string, wset, "")
    if result:
        result.pop() # Remove the empty string token
        result.reverse() # Put the list into correct order
        return result
    else:
        raise Exception("No possible segmentation!")

def tokenize(string, wset, token):
    """Returns either false if the string can't be segmented by 
    the current wset or a list of words that segment the string
    in reverse order."""
    # Are we done yet?
    if string == "":
        return [token]
    # Find all possible prefixes
    for pref in wset:
        if string.startswith(pref):
            res = tokenize(string.replace(pref, '', 1), wset, pref)
            if res:
                res.append(token)
                return res
    # Not possible
    return False

print segment("thisisinsane", ['this', 'is', 'in', 'insane']) # this is insane
print segment("shareasale", ['share', 'a', 'sale', 'as'])     # share a sale
print segment("asignas", ['as', 'sign', 'a'])                 # a sign as
```

Comment: Thank you @Jakub ! Even though Photon's answer solved my problem, this answer helped me better understand the solution with its clear explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a recursive scan, each time adding a single letter to the last word (if it's in the dictionary), and also trying letting it start a new word.  This means that at each call, you have either 1 or 2 hypotheses to test (whether there's a space or not).
When you reach the end of the input, and you have a valid set of words, save this solution, if the first word in it is longer than the best solution you've found so far.

Example code:

```
words=['share','as','a','sale','bla','other','any','sha','sh']
wdict={}
best=[]

def scan(input,i,prevarr):
    global best
    arr=list(prevarr)
    # If array is empty, we automatically add first letter
    if len(arr)<1:
        arr.append(input[0:1])
        return scan(input,i+1,arr)
    # If no more input is available, evaluate the solution
    if i>=len(input):
        # Is the last word a valid word
        if wdict.has_key(arr[-1]):
            # Is there a current best solution?
            if len(best)==0:
                best=arr      # No current solution so select this one
            elif len(arr[0])>len(best[0]):
                best=arr      # If new solution has a longer first word
        return best
    # If the last word in the sequence is a valid word, we can add a space and try
    if wdict.has_key(arr[-1]):
        arr.append(input[i:i+1])
        scan(input,i+1,arr)
        del arr[-1]
    # Add a letter to the last word and recurse
    arr[-1]=arr[-1]+input[i:i+1]
    return scan(input,i+1,arr)

def main():
    for w in words:
        wdict[w]=True
    res=scan('shareasasale',0,[])
    print res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @photon for taking the effort to write out a complete solution. It seems to work perfectly for my needs.

Comment: I was going through the code and finding it a little bit difficult to understand. I'd appreciate if you could explain the solution with comments.

Comment: Added comments.  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm I would use would be something like:

- Have your dictionary sorted by decreasing length
- Build a function `prefix(s)` which yields, in order, dictionary words which start `s`

  - ie. `prefix("informativecow")` yields first "informative", then "inform", then "info", then "in"
- Build a recursive function `test(s)` which:

  - if `s` is the empty string, returns True
  - for each prefix, remove the prefix from s and call `test()` with that string. If you find one that's true, return true. If you don't find any that are true, return False.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Dave, but Photon's answer has solved my problem. Nevertheless, I am curious will this work for 'asignas' => 'a' 'sign' 'as'.

Answer (score 0):

For a real-world example of how to do English word segmentation, look at the source of the [Python wordsegment module](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/wordsegment/). It's a little more sophisticated because it uses word and phrase frequency tables but it illustrates the memoization approach.

In particular, `score` illustrates the segmentation approach:

```
def score(word, prev=None):
    "Score a `word` in the context of the previous word, `prev`."

    if prev is None:
        if word in unigram_counts:

            # Probability of the given word.

            return unigram_counts[word] / 1024908267229.0
        else:
            # Penalize words not found in the unigrams according
            # to their length, a crucial heuristic.

            return 10.0 / (1024908267229.0 * 10 ** len(word))
    else:
        bigram = '{0} {1}'.format(prev, word)

        if bigram in bigram_counts and prev in unigram_counts:

            # Conditional probability of the word given the previous
            # word. The technical name is *stupid backoff* and it's
            # not a probability distribution but it works well in
            # practice.

            return bigram_counts[bigram] / 1024908267229.0 / score(prev)
        else:
            # Fall back to using the unigram probability.

            return score(word)
```

If you replaced the score function so that it returned higher scores for longer matches in your dictionary then it would do as you want.